# What is the notation $PQ$ supposed to mean for subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, notation

My notes just jumps to it without prior explanation like I am supposed to know it. I don't.

It's talking about Sylow p-groups and such,

> $A$ is a group and let $P,Q$ be sylow $p,q$-groups respectively ...etc...Now $PQ$ is a subgroup of $A$, and ...etc... thus, in fact $PQ=A$.

I've omitted the paragraphs that are long and goes through explanation which is all fine but I don't know what it means by $PQ$. What, $P$ acting on $Q$? But shouldn't that be $P \cdot Q$ to be clearer? Direct products have $\times$ so that can't be it either.

Anything else? Does someone know?

Comment: As Michael Hardy notes, most authors simply mean the set of products of an element from $P$ times an element from $Q$.  The claim that $PQ$ is a *subgroup* is a synthetic proposition (in the sense of Kant), saying something more than just the definition of $PQ$ and requiring the justification by those "paragraphs that are long and [go] through explanation".

Answer (score 3):

Usually it's defined as $PQ = \{ab : a\in P\ \&\ b\in Q\}$.